# Polymer, add item to dom repeat without rebuilding all elements

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

So at the moment I have a dom repeat that creates new elements for each item. Each element then does its own iron-ajax requests.

Now when I add an item to that dom repeat is rebuilds every elements and therefore does all the iron-requests and builds the dom.

I was wondering if there is a way around this, so that it just builds the element from the new item and not all the others with it.

We are building a full application using polymer and it is suffering from performance issues, not from the requests but from building the elements we believe.

Comment: There may ways, please add your recent code than we can build on this.

Comment: call `iron-ajax `only once. Trigger `ajax call` from repeating components after `event trigger`

Answer (score 0):

`dom-repeat` shouldn't 'rebuild' every element every time you add an item. It depends though, how you are adding items to your array.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]">
    [[item]]
</template>
```

This will 'rebuild' each item:

```
console.log(this.items); // prints ['a', 'b', 'c']
const i = this.items;
i.push('d');
this.items = [];
this.items = i;
```

This won't 'rebuild' each item:

```
console.log(this.items); // prints ['a', 'b', 'c']
this.push('items', 'd');
```

Comment: In that situation if you change the property items, it will rebuild the whole repeat because the array has changed.

Comment: @Murphy I'm not sure what you want to tell me with your comment. What is "that situation"?

Comment: With the code you have written the dom is rebuilt when you add or remove an item from items.

Comment: Did you test it? I don't think that the second example will rebuild each item. `this.push('items', 'd');` will only add/remove the delta elements.

Comment: Yea its the exact code we are currently using in our app. Within the dom-repeat we have elements that use the items data, they do their own ajax calls and everytime we use that exact code the whole thing rebuilds and thus does all the ajax calls. It is a pain and later we will come back and think it through and try and fix it.